# Dropdown doesnt refresh in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have two drop downs when i select the first drop down my second drop down should load based on the selection. I am doing it in angular js. Used watch Event to load the drop down event

```
angular.module('myApp', ['']).controller('QMesaures', function ($scope) {

 $scope.$watch('ddlDepartment', function (newVal) {
            var DepartmentName = newVal.DepartmentName

         $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                data: JSON.stringify({ DepartmentName: DepartmentName }),
                url: "/QReport/GetProviders",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                   alert(data);
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.Providers = data;

                    });


                }
            });

        });

});



<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="QMesaures">
<select  ng-model="ddlProviders" ng-options="provider.ProviderName for provider in Providers"></select>
</div>
```

But  my problem is that I am getting data I could able to see the alert box but my second dropdown (Provider drop down) doesnt show value.

Please help me how to refresh the dropdown to show the values in angular js.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `$http` service or Something like Restangular to do `http` requests. This automatically initiates the digest loop once the data is gotten from the endpoint.
PS- You may need to remove dependency jQuery to learn angular properly so that you think in an angular way.

Comment: Evans Dianga I tried by using $http I could able to get the data but couldnt able to load to the drop down. Code changed  $http.get('/QardReport/GetProviders?DepartmentName=PEDIATRICS').success(function (data) {
          $scope.Providers = data
   });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be that when you reassign $scope.Providers, you lose track of the reference to 'Providers'. Try this instead:

```
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        angular.copy(data, $scope.Providers);
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a watcher on a variable that doesn't exist on this scope as far as I can tell.  $scope.ddlDepartment is undefined from the code you have shown.